# Need assistance locating the errors within the following code

Tags: java

The code attached below is suppose to produce this output:

```
The array is: 4 3 6 9 3 9 5 4 1 9
This array DOES contain 5.
Sorted by Arrays.sort(): 1 3 3 4 4 5 6 9 9 9
Sorted by Sweep Sort: 1 3 3 4 4 5 6 9 9 9
Sorted by Selection Sort: 1 3 3 4 4 5 6 9 9 9
Sorted by Insertion Sort: 1 3 3 4 4 5 6 9 9 9
```

But it doesn't. I followed the instruction in the book that I am reading and it didn't help. Can I get your opinion on what those errors might be? I'm not asking for solutions, I want to be pointed in the right direction as to where the errors are and what type of errors they are.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class looks like it's meant to provide a few public static methods
 * for searching and sorting arrays.  It also has a main method that tests
 * the searching and sorting methods.
 * 
 * TODO: The search and sort methods in this class contain bugs that can
 * cause incorrect output or infinite loops.  Use the Eclipse debugger to 
 * find the bugs and fix them
 */

public class BuggySearchAndSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] A = new int[10];  // Create an array and fill it with small random ints.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            A[i] = 1 + (int)(10 * Math.random());

        int[] B = A.clone();   // Make copies of the array.
        int[] C = A.clone();
        int[] D = A.clone();

        System.out.print("The array is:");
        printArray(A);

        if (contains(A,5))
            System.out.println("This array DOES contain 5.");
        else
            System.out.println("This array DOES NOT contain 5.");

        Arrays.sort(A);  // Sort using Java's built-in sort method!
        System.out.print("Sorted by Arrays.sort():  ");
        printArray(A);   // (Prints a correctly sorted array.)

        bubbleSort(B);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Bubble Sort:    ");
        printArray(B);

        selectionSort(C);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Selection Sort: ");
        printArray(C);

        insertionSort(D);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Insertion Sort: ");
        printArray(D);

    }

    /**
     * Tests whether an array of ints contains a given value.
     * @param array a non-null array that is to be searched
     * @param val the value for which the method will search
     * @return true if val is one of the items in the array, false if not
     */
    public static boolean contains(int[] array, int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == val)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This inefficient sorting
     * method simply sweeps through the array, exchanging neighboring elements
     * that are out of order.  The number of times that it does this is equal
     * to the length of the array.
     */
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; i++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { // swap elements j and j+1
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This method uses a selection
     * sort algorithm, in which the largest item is found and placed at the end of 
     * the list, then the second-largest in the next to last place, and so on.
     */
    public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
        for (int top = array.length - 1; top > 0; top--) {
            int positionOfMax = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= top; i++) {
                if (array[1] > array[positionOfMax])
                    positionOfMax = i;
            }
            int temp = array[top];  // swap top item with biggest item
            array[top] = array[positionOfMax];
            array[positionOfMax] = temp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This method uses a standard
     * insertion sort algorithm, in which each element in turn is moved downwards
     * past any elements that are greater than it.
     */
    public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
        for (int top = 1; top < array.length; top++) {
            int temp = array[top];  // copy item that into temp variable
            int pos = top - 1;
            while (pos > 0 && array[pos] > temp) {
                   // move items that are bigger than temp up one position
                array[pos+1] = array[pos];
                pos--;
            }
            array[pos] = temp;  // place temp into last vacated position
        }
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the ints in an array on one line, separated by spaces,
     * with a line feed at the end.
     */
    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Time to learn to debug. Either run your code through a debugger or use println statements to see why it is not behaving correctly.

Comment: Will debugging, tell me what kind of error it is or would it give me some generic error statement?

Comment: Debugging will help you determine the issue. It will not directly tell you it though. Debugger != Magic. Also, please show your output so we can compare with the desired result.

Comment: If you fill the array randomly, why do you expect it to always contain `{ 4, 3, 6, 9, 3, 9, 5, 4, 1, 9 }`?  First try explicitly setting it to contain those values in that order, and see if it works properly then.  If not, it's debugging time, and additional information would help locate the issue.

Comment: I see, nice coding pun btw and the out put I am getting is 

The array is: 1 8 9 9 5 10 5 4 3 3
This array DOES NOT contain 5.
Sorted by Arrays.sort():   1 3 3 4 5 5 8 9 9 10

Comment: Remove the `else` in the contains.

Comment: *"Will debugging, tell me what kind of error it is or would it give me some generic error statement?"* No.  A debugger will allow you to see what the program is doing.  Figuring out what is wrong, why it is wrong, what causes it and how to fix it is up to something with grey matter between its ears.  Obviously, the grey matter *must be trained* to do this.  We are recommending that you train >>your<< grey matter.

Comment: Your code said that array didn't contain 5 because `1 == 5` is the first comparison, and it immediately returns false

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. BTW, is the debugger in netbeans ide a good one?

Comment: Change this line: `for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; i++) {`  for this: `for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {` in `bubbleSort` function.

Comment: @Tdorno OP's sorts don't create new arrays, they modify the arrays which were passed in. These methods can stay void as they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; i++) { //<---- wrong increment. it should be j++
                if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { // swap elements j and j+1
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in this part is at least one error. You should check your loops if your programm does not determine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have finished my project and decided to drop a help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] A = new int[10];  // Create an array and fill it with small random ints.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        A[i] = 1 + (int)(10 * Math.random());
    
    int[] B = A.clone();   // Make copies of the array.
    int[] C = A.clone();
    int[] D = A.clone();
    
    System.out.print("The array is:");
    printArray(A);
    
    if (contains(A,5))
        System.out.println("This array DOES contain 5.");
    else
        System.out.println("This array DOES NOT contain 5.");
    
    Arrays.sort(A);  // Sort using Java's built-in sort method!
    System.out.print("Sorted by Arrays.sort():  ");
    printArray(A);   // (Prints a correctly sorted array.)

    sweepSort(B);
    System.out.print("Sorted by Sweep Sort:    "); //Changed name 
    printArray(B);

    selectionSort(C);
    System.out.print("Sorted by Selection Sort: ");
    printArray(C);
    
    insertionSort(D);
    System.out.print("Sorted by Insertion Sort: ");
    printArray(D);

}


public static boolean contains(int[] array, int val) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val)
            return true;
                                                            //removed else
    }                                                       //removed return false;
    return false;
}


public static void sweepSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) { //'i++' => 'j++'
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { // swap elements j and j+1
                int temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int top = array.length - 1; top > 0; top--) {
        int positionOfMax = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= top; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[positionOfMax]) //replaced [1]
                positionOfMax = i;
        }
        int temp = array[top];  // swap top item with biggest item
        array[top] = array[positionOfMax];
        array[positionOfMax] = temp;
    }
}

public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int top = 1; top < array.length; top++) {
        int temp = array[top];  // copy item that into temp variable
        int pos = top - 1;
        while (pos >= 0 && array[pos] >= temp) { // '>' => '>='
               // move items that are bigger than temp up one position
            array[pos+1] = array[pos];
            pos--;
        }
        array[pos+1] = temp;  // place temp into last vacated position //added '+1' 
    }
}


private static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank for all your help guys. Using the debugger I found the for main issues

Error 1:

```
public static void sweepSort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; i++) {<------// need change i++ to j++
                if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { // swap elements j and j+1
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error 2 and 3:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
        for (int top = 1; top < array.length; top++) {
            int temp = array[top];  // copy item that into temp variable
            int pos = top - 1;
            while (pos > 0 && array[pos] > temp) { //<----- need to change '>' to '>='
                   // move items that are bigger than temp up one position
                array[pos+1] = array[pos];
                pos--;
            }
            array[pos ] = temp;  // place temp into last vacated position // <------------------------need to change 'array[pos ]' to 'array[pos + 1]'
        }
    }
```

Error 4:

```
   public static boolean contains(int[] array, int val) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] == val)
                    return true;
                else  //<---------- need to remove this
                return false; //<---------- need to remove this
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
package sort;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class looks like it's meant to provide a few public static methods
 * for searching and sorting arrays.  It also has a main method that tests
 * the searching and sorting methods.
 * 
 * TODO: The search and sort methods in this class contain bugs that can
 * cause incorrect output or infinite loops.  Use the Eclipse debugger to 
 * find the bugs and fix them
 */
public class BuggySearchAndSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] A = new int[10];  // Create an array and fill it with small random ints.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            A[i] = 1 + (int)(10 * Math.random());

        int[] B = A.clone();   // Make copies of the array.
        int[] C = A.clone();
        int[] D = A.clone();

        System.out.print("The array is:");
        printArray(A);

        if (contains(A,5))
            System.out.println("This array DOES contain 5.");
        else
            System.out.println("This array DOES NOT contain 5.");

        Arrays.sort(A);  // Sort using Java's built-in sort method!
        System.out.print("Sorted by Arrays.sort():  ");
        printArray(A);   // (Prints a correctly sorted array.)

        bubbleSort(B);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Bubble Sort:    ");
        printArray(B);

        selectionSort(C);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Selection Sort: ");
        printArray(C);

        insertionSort(D);
        System.out.print("Sorted by Insertion Sort: ");
        printArray(D);

    }

    /**
     * Tests whether an array of ints contains a given value.
     * @param array a non-null array that is to be searched
     * @param val the value for which the method will search
     * @return true if val is one of the items in the array, false if not
     */
    public static boolean contains(int[] array, int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == val)
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This inefficient sorting
     * method simply sweeps through the array, exchanging neighboring elements
     * that are out of order.  The number of times that it does this is equal
     * to the length of the array.
     */
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j+1]) { // swap elements j and j+1
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This method uses a selection
     * sort algorithm, in which the largest item is found and placed at the end of 
     * the list, then the second-largest in the next to last place, and so on.
     */
    public static void selectionSort(int[] array) {
        for (int top = array.length - 1; top > 0; top--) {
            int positionOfMax = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[positionOfMax])
                    positionOfMax = i;
            }
            int temp = array[top];  // swap top item with biggest item
            array[top] = array[positionOfMax];
            array[positionOfMax] = temp;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts an array into non-decreasing order.  This method uses a standard
     * insertion sort algorithm, in which each element in turn is moved downwards
     * past any elements that are greater than it.
     */
    public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
        for (int top = 1; top < array.length; top++) {
            int temp = array[top];  // copy item that into temp variable
            int pos = top ;
            while (pos > 0 && array[pos-1] >= temp) {
                   // move items that are bigger than temp up one position
                array[pos] = array[pos-1];
                pos--;
            }
            array[pos] = temp;  // place temp into last vacated position
        }
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the ints in an array on one line, separated by spaces,
     * with a line feed at the end.
     */
    private static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you change?   Can you explain a bit?   Just dumping code in does not make a high quality answer.